# Recorrer array JSON con objetos indexados y longitud desconocida

Tags: javascript, json

me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de recorrer un objeto json con objetos anidados que únicamente se deja de recorrer cuando no se encuentran mas elementos. La longitud y nos niveles de anidamiento son desconocidos. Es del estilo del siguiente objeto, tiene tres claves y la tercera clave puede estar o no, en caso de estar seria un array con un objeto del mismo tipo que el padre y a su vez podría tener mas objetos dentro. Lo que quiero hacer es recorrer todos los objetos que hay en esta variable y extraerlos en un array sin anidamientos, es decir, si en total tengo 100 elementos extraerlo a un array de tamaño 100. Estoy usando JavaScript para esto

```
let json = [{
        "elem1": 1,
        "elem2": 2,
        "elem3": [{
            "elem1": 1,
            "elem2": 2,
            "elem3": {
                "elem1": 1,
                "elem2": 2,
                "elem3": 3
            }
        }]
    },
    {
        "elem1": 1,
        "elem2": 2,
    }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer una función recursiva que saque los elementos. Y con [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) aplanar el resultado en un solo array.

En el código de más abajo puedes ver cómo funciona. Aquí te explico las claves.

Esta es la función recursiva:

```js
function sacarValores(elemento) {
  if (Array.isArray(elemento)) {
    return elemento.map(sacarValores).flat();
  }
  else if (typeof elemento === 'object') {
    return sacarValores(Object.values(elemento)).flat();
  }
  return elemento;
}
```

Por cada elemento:

- Caso recursivo: Si es un array, saca los datos haciendo un [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), en el que cada elemento del array va ejecutarse con la misma función. Finalmente, aplana el resultado con `flat`.
- Caso recursivo: Si es un objeto, va a sacar los valores del objeto con [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), y de nuevo, los pasa a la función recursiva. Finalmente aplana el resultado con `flat`.
- Caso base: Y si no es array ni objeto, entonces devuelve el elemento mismo.

Así que ahora podemos llamar a la función `map` con el objeto original (`json`), pasando la función recursiva, y eso nos devolvera una lista plana con todos los resultados.

```js
const json = [{
        "elem1": 1,
        "elem2": 2,
        "elem3": [{
            "elem1": 1,
            "elem2": 2,
            "elem3": {
                "elem1": 1,
                "elem2": 2,
                "elem3": 3
            }
        }]
    },
    {
        "elem1": 1,
        "elem2": 2,
    }
];

function sacarValores(elemento) {
  if (Array.isArray(elemento)) {
    return elemento.map(sacarValores).flat();
  }
  else if (typeof elemento === 'object' && elemento !== null) {
    return sacarValores(Object.values(elemento)).flat();
  }
  return elemento;
}

elementos = sacarValores(json);
console.log(elementos);
```

Este código te funcionará con cualquier estructura de arrays y objetos. Y te devolverá los elementos que sean número, cadenas, booleanos, null, undefined, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Primero de todo, es un ejercicio básico de desarrollo. Deberías buscar un poco más antes de preguntar.

Igualmente, aquí tienes una aproximación:

```js
let json = [{
    "elem1": 1,
    "elem2": 2,
    "elem3": [{
      "elem1": 1,
      "elem2": 2,
      "elem3": {
        "elem1": 1,
        "elem2": 2,
        "elem3": 3
      }
    }]
  },
  {
    "elem1": 1,
    "elem2": 2,
  }
];

const recorreArray = (array) => {
  array.forEach(elemento => {
    Object.entries(elemento).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        recorreArray(value);
      } else {
        console.log(key, value)
      }
    });
  })
}

recorreArray(json);
```